# Perl script works fine on my computer, not on remote server

Tags: linux, perl

I have a perl script which takes some fields from an input text file and transforms them to generate a more useful (for me) text file.

When I run it on my Mac (with a very small file made of a few lines from the real file), it produces the correct output. It produces a few warnings, pasted below, nevertheless, the output is ok.

When I run this exact same script on my institution's server, it returns MANY more "Use of uninitialized value" warnings, and although it DOES create an output file, the contents of it are exactly the same, line by line, as the input file. I am also trying it with the small file I tested on my computer.

I have a feeling this has to do with the version of perl? I am not admin, so how can I i fix this?

Warnings returned on server:

```
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 48, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Clipped in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 53, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Cigar in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 59, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in negation (-) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 64, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Info in pattern match (m//) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 73, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Read_Seq in substr at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 91, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $X2 in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $Matched in addition (+) at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 97, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../perl/R2_Warrior.pl line 104, <R2_FILE> line 9.
```

Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my ($Line) = "";
my (@Split_Line) = ();
my (%All_read_and_info_HASH) = ();


open(R2_FILE,"R2_Sample.txt") || die "Sorry I couldn't open the INPUT file: $!\n";
open(OUTPUT, ">R2_Output.txt") || die "Sorry I couldnt create the OUTPUT file: $!\n";

while(<R2_FILE>){

    ### Elimina los \n
    ### Parte cada linea por tabuladores
    chomp;
    $Line = $_;
    @Split_Line = split(/\t+/, $Line);


    ### Guarda los campos de donde se obtiene el resto de la informacion
    my $Read_Name = $Split_Line[0];
    my $Read_ID = $Split_Line[3];
    my $Read_Cigar = $Split_Line[5];
    my $Read_Seq = $Split_Line[9];
    my $Read_Info = $Split_Line[14];


    #print "$Read_Name\t$Read_Cigar\t$Read_Seq\t$Read_Info\n";
    #<STDIN>;


    ##########################################################
    ### Llena el hash de hashes                            ###
    ### Key = $Read_Name                                   ###
    ### La segunda llave, i.e. 'Sequence' son cada uno de  ###
    ### los campos del 0 al 8 del PDF                      ###
    ##########################################################

    my($Clipped, $Matched, $X1, $X2, $Temporal_Seq);

    ### [0]: Guarda la secuencia del read 
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Sequence'} = $Read_Seq;


    ### [1]: Guarda el numero de nt 'clipeados'
    if ($Read_Cigar =~ /(\d+)S\d+M/){ $Clipped = $1; }
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Clipped_Nt'} = $Clipped;


    ### [2]: Guarda los primeros N nt de la secuencia completa del read
    $Temporal_Seq = substr($Read_Seq, 0, $Clipped);
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Non_R2_Sequence'} = $Temporal_Seq;
    $Temporal_Seq = "";


    ### [3]: Guarda el numero de nt matcheados a R2
    if ($Read_Cigar =~ /\d+S(\d+)M/){ $Matched = $1; }
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Matched_Nt'} = $Matched;


    ### [4]: Guarda los ultimos N nt de la secuencia completa del read (Las bases matcheadas a R2)
    $Temporal_Seq = substr($Read_Seq, -$Matched);
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Matched_Sequence'} = $Temporal_Seq;
    $Temporal_Seq = "";


    ### [5]: Guarda el CIGAR string
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'CIGAR'} = $Read_Cigar;


    if ($Read_Info =~ /\+(\d+),(\d+)M/){ 
    $X1 = $1; 
    $X2 = $2;

    #print "$X1\t$X2\n";
    #<STDIN>;
    }


    ### [6]: Guarda el numero X1
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Start'} = $X1;


    ### [7]: Guarda el numero X2
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Matched_NT'} = $X2;


    ### [8]: Guarda los primeros X2 nt de la secuencia completa del read
    $Temporal_Seq = substr($Read_Seq, 0, $X2);
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Matched_Sequence'} = $Temporal_Seq;
    $Temporal_Seq = "";


    ### [9]: Calcula 144-([3] + [7])
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Result'} = (144 - ($Matched + $X2));


    ### [10]: Guarda el sitio de R2 Truncation
    $All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Truncation'} = $Read_ID;


    print OUTPUT $Read_Name."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Sequence'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Clipped_Nt'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Non_R2_Sequence'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Matched_Nt'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Matched_Sequence'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'CIGAR'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Start'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Matched_NT'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'28s_Matched_Sequence'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Result'}."\t".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'R2_Truncation'}."\n";


    #print $Read_Name."\n".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Sequence'}."\n".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'First_N'}."\n".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Sequence'}."\n".$All_read_and_info_HASH{$Read_Name}{'Last_N'}."\n";

    #<STDIN>;
}
close(R2_FILE);
close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: Have you compared the versions of Perl? Does the script give correct output when used on smaller file on the server? The warnings you have mean that `@Split_Line = split(/\t+/, $Line);` did not work as expected, and none of the variables is initialized.

Comment: This question is off topic here (don't worry, it will probably be migrated automatically). Your problem is almost certainly that there is a different file on the server from what you tried locally so your `split` fails as suggested by @AlexeyIvanov. Also, when asking this kind of question, it is a good idea to include an example input file.

Comment: A often overlook trap is, that you have the wrong line endings (especially when mailing scripts). In my experience that could produce the most weired errors. So, how did you transfer the script to your server, and which OS are running on your machine and the institution's server?

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov The version on the Institution's server is actually more recent. v5.14.2, compared to v5.12.3 on the Mac. In fact I have only tested the script on the same smaller file that I ran on the computer.

Comment: @terdon I copied the file on the server to my mac via scp, so it is the same exact file :s I am attaching an example of the input file. :)

Comment: @mpy, I transfered the script by copying it from the editor on my Mac and pasting in on a new vi file. I wrote it on Smultron. Perhaps I should try scp?

Comment: @CarmenSandoval: That should be fine, even better than scp, because on Mac OS (up to version 9) the End Of Line terminator is `\r` whereas in Linux (and in Mac OX X) it's `\n`. With copy&paste you are usually save.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
my @Split_Line = split(/\t+/, $Line);
```

because you are setting it outside the loop's block.

You can also set your variables like so...

```
 my( $Read_Name,   $Read_ID ,$Read_Cigar , $Read_Seq , $Read_Info ) =  
      split(/\t+/, $Line);
```

Comment: Yes, `@Split_Line` declaration could be the cause. You may need to clear the array at the end of `while`. However, I'm not sure about it.

Comment: If you look closely at the script above, you'll see that some indexes are skipped, so your expression `my( $Read_Name,…)` wouldn't work. To skip a value, use `undef`: `my ($Read_Name, undef, undef, $Read_ID,…) = split(/\t+/, $Line);`.